# Where is the best place to add programming logic in a fragment ?

Tags: android, coding-style, android-fragments

I worked with fragments for a while now, and i want to ask you which is the **best practice** for adding programming logic when using `fragments`. 
I usually set click listeners and instantiate adapters etc... inside the `onCreateView` method right after inflating layout and instantiating views (TextViews EditTexts Lists).

What do you guys think is the best place to add logic within the fragment lifecycle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.I make layout and register listeners in

```
  onViewCreated();
```

2.This following two methods to handle resuming.

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    //do something
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally use `onViewCreated()` which according to the documentation is the method that is called after the layout is inflated into the layout.

It helps keeping the code clean and don't have one method implement all the logic.